# HTML elements semantics

Tags: html

What is the difference between the following code examples? I'd appreciate a few examples of where and how to use them. I know there must be some difference...

`<b>` and `<strong>`
`<i>` and `<em>`
`<center>` + `<b>`/`<strong>` and `<h1>`-`<h6>`

I am also wondering if there is an "alternative" for `<u>`...

Comment: Such issues are discussed (poorly) in HTML specifications and drafts and on discussion forums for them. There is no real consensus, just vague descriptions and opinions, so this is not suitable for a technical Q/A system.

Comment: This is `<strong><em>NOT</em></strong>` off-topic. Wrong close reason, to say the least.

Comment: I agree... Especially considering the answers. It should've been closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `<b>`, `<i>` and `<center>` is discouraged, because they do not add any meaning to the document's structure. Their presentational effect can be recreated with CSS.

`<strong>` and `<em>` are clearly more semantic, since their names imply the notion of an *emphasis*. Note that browsers will render `<strong>` as bold and `<em>` as italics by default, but this can be changed with CSS also, so they're not synonyms of `<b>` and `<i>`.

As for `<h1>` - `<h6>`, they represent six different levels of headings, and are used to give the content some hierarchy. Therefore, they are also semantically important.

And here is how to replace `<u>` with CSS (for example, on all elements with a class `underline`):

```
.underline { text-decoration: underline; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from the below link:

> i - Strictly a presentational element.  If you want text to be
>   italicized and not have any real semantic meaning, then wrap it in i
>   tags.
>
> b - Strictly a presentational element.  If you want text to be bold
>   and not have any real semantic meaning, then wrap it in b tags.
>
> em - Strictly a structure element.  If you want text to be spoken with
>   emphasis using a speech reader, then wrap it in em tags.
>
> strong - Strictly a structure element.  If you want text to be spoken
>   with strong emphasis using a speech reader, then wrap it in strong
>   tags.

[Source link](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum21/9344.htm)

Comment: Can you summarize the content of the linked page in case the URL changes?

Comment: A link is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Header-tags <h1>

The header tags are used for headers/headings. The difference of `<h1>` to `<h6>` is the "weight" of the heading. A lot of people say, that for SEO it's good to have just one `<h1>` per page to show what the page is about.

#### <b> and <i>

are both from a layout point of view doing the same as `<em>` and `<strong>` but they don't add semantics to the document. They are also deprecated in HTML5 and you should not use them anymore. Everything they brought in style can be achieved with CSS and everything they lack in semantics is covered by `<em>` and `<strong>`.

#### <u>

has been deprecated a long time ago (with XHTML1?) and you should use something like this instead:

```
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">underline text</span>
```

As a `<span>`is "semantic neutral" it doesn't add any value to the content.